# Using multiprocessing with a void method/setter method

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm still new to multiprocessing but have done a lot of reading over the past couple of days and want to see if something I had in mind was feasible using multiprocessing.

A lot of examples of multiprocessing online look like the following:

```
def worker():
    print('Worker')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

But the example methods for multiprocessing always return or print something! Is there a way I can do the following?

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level=0
    def setLevel(self,val):
        self.level=val

def method(worker, level):
     worker.setLevel(level)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        jobs.append(Worker())
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool()
    for i in range(5):
       worker=jobs[i]
       res = pool.apply_async(method, args=(worker,i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for worker in jobs:
        print(worker.level)
```

I know `apply_async` returns a result object, whose value you can get with `Result.get()`, but that doesn't seem useful in such a setting like the one I've described.

When I execute the following code, I get `0 0 0 0 0` instead of the desired `0 1 2 3 4` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's no requirement to return something from a function passed to `Pool.appy_async()`, but in this case it's necessary in order to update the corresponding `Worker` object in the `jobs` list that exist only in the main process.

This is because when `multiprocessing`, each process runs in its own memory-space, which means you cannot share global variables among them. There's ways to simulate that, but it's generally entails a lot of overhead and may actually defeat any gains from doing the multiprocessing. Each sub-process is getting passed a *copy* of the `Worker` object.

Taking that into consideration, here's one way to make your code work. The `method()` function now returns (a copy) of the updated `Worker` object to the main process which stores all the result objects associated with each one in a separate list named `results`. When all the jobs have been processed following the `pool.join()` call, that list is then used to replace each `Worker` object that was originally put into the `jobs` list — only making it only *appear* as though they've updated themselves.

```
import multiprocessing


class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0

    def setLevel(self,val):
        self.level = val


def method(worker, level):
    worker.setLevel(level)
    return worker  # ADDED - return updated Worker object.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        jobs.append(Worker())

    results = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for i in range(5):
        worker = jobs[i]
        results.append(pool.apply_async(method, (worker, i)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Update Workers in jobs list.
    for i, result in enumerate(results):
        jobs[i] = result.get()  # Replace workers with their updated version.

    for worker in jobs:
        print(worker.level)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is extremely disappointing that you'd have to rewrite the code in such a way but at least I have an answer now

Comment: Anthony: Depending on exactly the worker function actually does, multithreading might be a better approach because it's possible share global objects and data when using it (if you do it properly). It's not the best choice for if worker does a lot of computation however (unlike what's being done in this trivial example).

Comment: I'm learning about multiprocessing to speed up an algorithm I wrote that uses the lxml library to parse an XML file into a tree, then (with multiprocessing) label its Element nodes from a top-down approach (starting with parents with the most children and working your way down). I think my algorithm does involve a lot of computation because it uses the entire processor (12.5%) on large files and slows down tremendously. I've experimented with ThreadPoolExecutor but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly (didn't work when I tried it)

Comment: Anthony: In Python threading's best suited for I/O bound tasks because it allows other tasks to run while others wait for I/O to complete. When using it, you have to be careful about controlling concurrent access to shared resources like global variables. Multiprocessing can help speed-up computationally-bound tasks, but collecting intermediate results to produce the final one can slow everything down again. The challenge in doing concurrent processing is often designing a way to do what needs to be done that avoids or at least minimizes the need to share data — to make the tasks independent.